# How to debug CUPS not sending jobs to printer?

Tags: cups, nixos

tl;dr: Rather than just try a bunch of stuff until things work and then try another bunch of stuff next it breaks, how can I go about systematically understanding why CUPS is telling me jobs are completed when they are not?

I just installed and configured NixOS from scratch, and was happy to find that it has detected my printer without any manual configuration *and* was able to print the first job I sent it. However, after that first job it refuses to print anything else. I've tried restarting the printer, rebooting my PC, restarting the program I'm printing from, removing and reconfiguring the printer, changing the printer driver, and changing various printer settings. Nothing works, and there's absolutely no indication that anything is wrong except for the fact that the printer seems to know nothing of these jobs. Anything I try printing ends up in the printer queue for a few minutes with a status like

> processing since
> [datetime]
> "Connected to printer."

after which the status changes to "completed" with absolutely no indication that the printer has received the document, much less printed it.

The autodetected printer is showing up as "HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M281fdn_4FDF62_" with a driver called "HP HP ColorLaserJet MFP M278-M281" and is connected via Ethernet. Both the printer and PC are behind the same router.

The `journalctl --catalog --follow --unit=cups` output:

```
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: [Job ???] Request file type is application/pdf.
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: Adding start banner page "none".
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: Adding end banner page "none".
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: File of type application/pdf queued by "username".
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: Queued on "HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M281fdn_4FDF62" by "username".
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: Started filter /nix/store/bjh98ajz51yzm7gyphx7x417spwkjkxj-cups-progs/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 44792)
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: Started backend /nix/store/bjh98ajz51yzm7gyphx7x417spwkjkxj-cups-progs/lib/cups/backend/ipp (PID 44795)
Jul 23 14:03:52 hostname cupsd[1728]: REQUEST localhost - - "POST /printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M281fdn_4FDF62 HTTP/1.1" 200 828451 Print-Job successful-ok
Jul 23 14:03:53 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
Jul 23 14:03:54 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
Jul 23 14:03:55 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
Jul 23 14:03:56 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
Jul 23 14:03:56 hostname cupsd[1728]: HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M281fdn_4FDF62 username 17 [23/Jul/2021:14:03:56 +1200] total 1 - localhost document.pdf - one-sided
Jul 23 14:03:56 hostname cupsd[1728]: Job completed.
Jul 23 14:03:56 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
Jul 23 14:03:57 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
Jul 23 14:04:06 hostname cupsd[1728]: Saving printers.conf...
Jul 23 14:04:06 hostname cupsd[1728]: Saving job.cache...
Jul 23 14:04:06 hostname cupsd[1728]: Saving subscriptions.conf...
Jul 23 14:04:06 hostname cupsd[1728]: Expiring subscriptions...
```

I've tried swapping hplip with hplipWithPlugin, and that did not help.

For the record, I was able to print again after setting up the printer using [`system-config-printer`](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/unable-to-install-hp-printer-with-proprietary-driver-despite-setting-allowunfree-true-in-etc-nixos-configuration-nix/7741/12?u=l0b0), but the question still stands: how do I debug this sort of situation?